# Wrong last day of month

Tags: java, calendar, java-6

Where is some function to get the last day of month in my service?

```
 DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
        Date date = format.parse(stringDate);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(date);

        calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);

        Date lastDayOfMonth = calendar.getTime();

        DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

        return sdf.format(lastDayOfMonth);
```

So, this method correctly works elsewhere, but in US last day is always 29 (last day - 1)

stringDate is date in format "yyyy-MM-dd"

Comment: What is the `stringDate` value?

Comment: Because it begins from 0, see the API.

Comment: @waldermar, you have provided us the **format** of `stringDate` but **not** the **actual value** of `stringDate`. Provide us 2 or more actual values that will validate your question, include your US date (if you get my question).

Comment: @MarounMaroun You're right MONTH begins at 0, and DATE begins at 1

Comment: Your code works correctly on my german machine. What exactly do you mean with "in US"? Machines located in the US? Machines with an OS set to be US? Some kind of US specific JVM?

Comment: Btw `DAY_OF_MONTH` and `DATE` are synonyms.

Comment: for ex.: I have date like "2014-11-10", I have to get "2014-11-30", if date is "2000-12-02" I have to get "2014-12-31". I get

Comment: my clients live in USA and they have wrong result. If I get  "2014-11-30" they get  "2014-11-29". If I get "2014-12-31", they get "2014-12-30"

Comment: Why not set leniency to `false` **before** doing date format/parse `format.setLenient(false);` and `sdf.setLenient(false);`. See if this solves the issue.

Comment: Maybe this problem is related to timezone difference issues. If your service is running in a specific timezone and the US machines in another one, there could be conversion problems in your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this problem is due to [Day Light saving time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time_in_the_United_States) in US.

You can change this by setting the Timezone for Calendar to different timezone.

Related question: [Adding days with java.util.Calendar gives strange results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7691855/adding-days-with-java-util-calendar-gives-strange-results)

Answer (score 1):

Java Date has very poor API. Instead of this I would recommend you to use [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/).

In Joda it would look like this:

```
LocalDate endOfMonth = date.dayOfMonth().withMaximumValue();
```

Comment: please don't do that, Java 8 has much better Date API

Comment: Not much better but slightly.  PS not every one is so lucky to use Java 8 ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have Java 8, this is very compact with JodaTime.

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;

public class SoLastDay {
    public DateTime lastDay(final String yyyy_MM_dd) {
        DateTime givenDate = new DateTime(yyyy_MM_dd);
        return givenDate.dayOfMonth().withMaximumValue();
    }
}
```

And a small test...

```
@Test
public void testLastDay() throws Exception {
    SoLastDay soLastDay = new SoLastDay();

    String date1 = "2015-01-27";
    System.out.printf("Date %s becomes %s.\n", date1, soLastDay.lastDay(date1).toString("yyyy-MM-dd"));

    String date2 = "2015-02-02";
    System.out.printf("Date %s becomes %s.\n", date2, soLastDay.lastDay(date2).toString("yyyy-MM-dd"));

}
```

And the test results:

```
Date 2015-01-27 becomes 2015-01-31.
Date 2015-02-02 becomes 2015-02-28.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you *do* have Java 8, you might use code like this:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjusters;

public class SoLastDayJava8 {
    static DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");

    public LocalDate lastDay(final String yyyy_MM_dd) {
        LocalDate givenDate = LocalDate.parse(yyyy_MM_dd, formatter);
        return givenDate.with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth());
    }
}
```

The test code changes just a bit.

```
public class SoLastDayJava8Test {

    @Test
    public void testLastDay() throws Exception {
        SoLastDayJava8 soLastDay = new SoLastDayJava8();

        String date1 = "2015-01-27";
        System.out.printf("Date %s becomes %s.\n", date1, soLastDay.lastDay(date1));

        String date2 = "2015-02-02";
        System.out.printf("Date %s becomes %s.\n", date2, soLastDay.lastDay(date2));

    }
}
```

But the results are the same.

> Date 2015-01-27 becomes 2015-01-31.
>
> Date 2015-02-02 becomes 2015-02-28.

Answer (score 0):

You are messing with the `TimeZones`.

When you execute `Date date = format.parse(stringDate);` you are creating a `Date` object with the `TimeZone` of the `DateFormat` object. Theoretically if the `TimeZone` is the same for all your `DateFormat` and `Calendar` objects, you should be fine. Check if they are coherent with the `getTimeZone()` method.

If the `TimeZone` of the first `DateFormat` is wrong (e.g. is your `TimeZone` or `UTC` or `GMT`), you'll get a `UTC-008` conversion in the second `TimeZone` (and in the `Calendar`) resulting in the missing day since you start from midnight.

Judging from your code is the `stringDate` itself that has been wrongly converted somewhere else...